# Is Chief Okko still trapped?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, the-rise-of-skywalker

Recall in *Star Wars: Empire’s End* issue 1, the Emperor blows a gasket when the initial firing of the Galaxy Gun does not go as planned. This in turn reveals his fraught deteriorating condition of his final clone body.

This causes the Emperor an immediate emergency to quickly get some spare bodies.

He then goes to Ossus to harvest some Force-sensitive Ysanna to serve as immediate replacement bodies.

His Dark Jedi slab them up in carbonite…
[image]

But…
[image]

They included a unique special feature different from what was done with, say, Han Solo:

> That’s our secret, Skywalker. **Only the Emperor can unfreeze your friends.**

Unfortunately, the Emperor meets an untimely death. There was no indication, and in fact, generally impossible circumstances for Skywalker to have obtained the secret to freeing the Ysanna before the Emperor’s death.

And in any case, he ultimately dies a final death under any circumstance in canon in *Star Wars Episode IX: The Rise of Skywalker*, again without any indication in any post-2012 Legends continuity, that anyone bothered to remember to free Okko.

Is Chief Okko and the carbonited Ysanna still slabbed in carbonite?

Comment: is there any indication that this character and what happened to him exists in the canon timeline? This should be narrowed down to only ask about canon or legends. Otherwise you're effectively asking a question about two distinct parralel timelines basically. Also, while funny, the zoomed in pictures are a little much :)

Comment: My question actually is intended to be whether Okko (the Ysanna) have been officially freed at all, ever.  There is a single answer to that if they have been in any timeline. I figure this question is esoteric enough that such a generalized form is sufficient and that we probably don’t need essentially two separate questions to address whether Okko remains wall art. But if people feel Okko is suitably significant in Star Wars canon, then a sibling question can be generated, but it’ll likely be subjected to post abuse with tangential side issues whether he exists in current canon, etc.

Comment: my basic argument is that if you are citing Rise of Skywalker, then the events of "Dark Empire" never even happened so it's not really a good question :) I think if it was targeted just to legends and the reference to post-Rise of Skywalker removed then it's perfectly fine

Comment: I’m not passing any judgment on how any pre-2012 continuity could be possibly extrapolated to shoehorn in post-2012 immovable events. Merely rather, an important element of the question is the secret lies with the Emperor. So consequently, the death(s) of the Emperor may be significant to prospective answers. Being canon, the 35ABY (final, FINAL) death of the Emperor may serve as an absolute boundary condition to the events at question.

Comment: but again, it's one or the other. If you're talking about Dark Empire events, then RoS didn't happen, so that reference is just confusing and unnecessary. There's no reason to clutter the question with it.

Comment: LFL only addressed its new canon moving forward; it has never addressed, nor in fact moved forward with its old now-Legends canon to presume how that old now-Legends continuity would or could accommodate the post-2012 canon. Given that Dark Nest flowwalking & The World  Between Worlds can allow for an infinite number of Expandy-Universy ways Dark Empire and RoS events _could_ occur, including “it’s one or the other” being one of those, but right now it’s all just anyone’s head-canon.

Comment: By LFL’s own 2012 “Legendary Star Wars” statement introducing new canon and Legends, it’s clear that the 35ABY death of the Emperor in RoS is intended to serve as an immovable event in any official Star Wars story; whether this new lease on finding the secret offers Okko any new hope or not, I don’t quite know. Which is why I asked the question. I think it might have bearing in any prospective answer related to my question, but perhaps not.  But if I knew the answer rather than just the question, I wouldn’t need to ask the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132986/discussion-between-silly-but-true-and-nkcampbell).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Unknown as of 2008

The 2008 *The Complete Star Wars Encyclopedia* has the most recent reference to Okko that I've been able to find. His entry ends with:

> The resurrected Emperor, his clone forms ailing, needed Jedi blood to secure his grip on immortality. To that end, dark side enforcers captured three Ysanna shamans for their cloning experiments, including Okko. Captive and transported to the planet Vjun, Okko was frozen in carbonite to await the Emperor's clonemasters. The carbon slabs lacked controls, and the de-carbonization process was an Imperial secret. **His fate was a mystery.**
>
> (Volume II, p 406, emphasis added)

That he was never freed seems like the simplest explanation (or Okko's Razor, if you prefer).

Comment: Great find! Also interesting slight modification of the source: “only the Emperor can unfreeze him” is a wholly different thing from “his de-carbonization process was an Imperial secret.” The latter may still offer the briefest of additional hope that the secret could still be buried in some still-existing Imperial files rather than solely subject to Palpatine’s now-ended memory or powers.